# On page loading or 2nd pagination query does not fire properly in listing page

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a offer percent filter in dropdown.

On onchange product listing page displays correct data on first loading page. But from second loading page it does not display correct result.

On listing page I have applied below query -

```
if($this->getRequest()->getParam('offers') == 'off_10_percent')
{
    $_productCollection     = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->Clear()->addAttributeToFilter('ratio_value', array('lt' => 0.10))->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
}
else if($this->getRequest()->getParam('offers') == 'off_15_percent')
{
    $_productCollection     = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->Clear()->addAttributeToFilter('ratio_value', array('gteq' => 0.10))->addAttributeToFilter('ratio_value', array('lt' => 0.15))->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
}
else if($this->getRequest()->getParam('offers') == 'off_20_percent')
{       
    $_productCollection     = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->Clear()->addAttributeToFilter('ratio_value', array('gteq' => 0.15))->addAttributeToFilter('ratio_value', array('lt' => 0.20))->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
}
else if($this->getRequest()->getParam('offers') == 'off_25_percent')
{       
    $_productCollection     = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->Clear()->addAttributeToFilter('ratio_value', array('gteq' => 0.20))->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');

}   
else
{
    $_productCollection     = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->Clear()->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc'); 
}
```

Sql query

```
 SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`couple_band_sku`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`design_family`, `e`.`design_family_value`, `e`.`design_sequence`, `e`.`karat`, `e`.`karat_value`, `e`.`expected_delivery_days`, `e`.`gender`, `e`.`gender_value`, `e`.`height`, `e`.`width`, `e`.`total_no_stones_in_metal`, `e`.`total_no_stones_in_metal_value`, `e`.`special_occassion`, `e`.`metal_total_weight`, `e`.`stone_price`, `e`.`top_seller`, `e`.`stone`, `e`.`stone_value`, `e`.`stone_color`, `e`.`stone_color_value`, `e`.`stone_shape`, `e`.`stone_shape_value`, `e`.`total_weight`, `e`.`platinum_default`, `e`.`rose_gold_default`, `e`.`white_gold_default`, `e`.`yellow_gold_default`, `e`.`category_banner`, `e`.`candere_product_type`, `e`.`candere_product_type_value`, `e`.`chain_length`, `e`.`chain_length_value`, `e`.`bracelets_length`, `e`.`bracelets_length_value`, `e`.`discard_from_price_rules`, `e`.`top_thickness`, `e`.`top_height`, `e`.`bottom_thickness`, `e`.`diamond_gemstone_weight`, `e`.`default_metal_weight`, `e`.`disable_shop_now`, `e`.`gemstone_color`, `e`.`gemstone_color_value`, `e`.`goldcoin_purity`, `e`.`goldcoin_purity_value`, `e`.`is_emi_enabled`, `e`.`chain_thickness`, `e`.`is_available_in_exchange`, `e`.`kada_ring_size`, `e`.`kada_ring_size_value`, `e`.`is_hallmarked`, `e`.`producturlattribute`, `e`.`deals_ring_sizer`, `e`.`deals_ring_sizer_value`, `e`.`most_viewed`, `e`.`off`, `e`.`offers`, `e`.`offers_value`, `e`.`off_10_percent`, `e`.`off_10_percent_value`, `e`.`off_20_percent`, `e`.`off_20_percent_value`, `e`.`p_30`, `e`.`off_30_percent`, `e`.`off_30_percent_value`, `e`.`metal_weight_rings`, `e`.`metal_weight_rings_value`, `e`.`metal_weight_bangle`, `e`.`metal_weight_bangle_value`, `e`.`metal_weight_chains`, `e`.`solitaire_size`, `e`.`most_product_clicked`, `e`.`most_product_clicked_value`, `e`.`ratio_10_percent`, `e`.`ratio_10_percent_value`, `e`.`ratio`, `e`.`ratio_value`, `e`.`ratio_value`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`platinum_default`, `e`.`rose_gold_default`, `e`.`white_gold_default`, `e`.`yellow_gold_default` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='139' AND cat_index.is_parent=1 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` desc, `cat_index_position` asc, `cat_index`.`position` asc LIMIT 10000
```

Can anyone guide or explain why it happened or any solution?

Comment: Where are you using these condition. I mean which file ?

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal test\app\design\frontend\default\new_design_test\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

Comment: Try to edit  /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php file by copying it to local directory. There is a function protected function _getProductCollection()  which is actually loaded when we get catalog listing. Try to edit and customize here not in phtml file

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal thank you - I will definitely try

Comment: If still you face problem I am always here :)

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal Sorry for the late reply. Just now I saw - thank u :)